# How to select only a part of a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have table cells with an image on the left. Now, every time one taps the cell, the image changes, but I only want the image to change when the left area of the cell is tapped. How can I do this?

Right now I have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    if (cell.imageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxfull.png"]) {

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxblank.png"];
    }
    else if(cell.imageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxblank.png"]) {

      cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxfull.png"];
      //[alert show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A table cell is just an `UIView`. Make a custom cell and use a `UIImageView` subclass or a button that responds to your taps.

Or use `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` of the table cell and compute the location.

For information on table cells look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Comment: I'm totally monkey on this one. Can you explain a bit more please please please...thanks

Comment: Have a look at this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to add a 'UIGestureRecognizer' for each 'UIImageView' see [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
To determine wich image was selected use tags...

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more help to Erik's great answer, I only call super if it's where I want it.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = touches.anyObject;
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.addRemoveButton];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.addRemoveButton.bounds, location))
    {
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```